# Rsync not deleting files in destination directory despite “--delete” being set

Tags: rsync

I have the following rsync command:

```
rsync -ahv --progress --delete \
    /source_dir1/file1.txt \
    /source_dir2 \
    /dest_dir/
```

It syncs everything as expected, but does not delete anything from `dest_dir` as I would expect: for example, I created `dest_dir/should_delete.txt` and `dest_dir/should_delete`, but neither the text file nor the directory delete.

Is it something to do with the fact I'm syncing `/source_dir2` instead of `/source_dir2/`? I prefer to do it that way to maintain the directory structure.

Comment: “I prefer to do it that way to maintain the directory structure.” I think you might be mixed up. Try doing the directory cop with `--dry-run` (to just see what would happen) and then like this: `rsync -ahv --progress --delete /source_dir1/file1.txt /source_dir2/ /dest_dir`. The directory structure _might_ be `/dest_dir/source_dir2/` but I think you can correct it. I believe the trailing slash on the source only copies the _contents_ of the directory. As such would not delete files in the destination. Read up in this [Stack Overflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31278462/117259).

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain myself well: I want the destination directory to contain `file1.txt` and `source_dir2`, as opposed to `file1.txt` and the contents of `source_dir2`. Leaving off the trailing slash gives the former, as desired.

Comment: But yes, you are correct that leaving the trailing slash off deletes the files as desired, but now I'm left with the files that I would prefer to have within a subdirectory synced to the top level directory `dest_dir`.

Comment: Good question. Odd case. Wish I knew more or had more time to help. But at least you now know why the files weren’t being deleted!

Comment: Thanks anyway, appreciate it!